# Observations and confusions while calling C/++ functions

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, syntax

Why can you call C/C++ functions like this:

```
(&myAwesomefunction)(arg1,arg2,arg3...);
```

Surely taking the address of a function gives you a pointer/address. And as I understand it pointers are not callable as functions. What's really happening?

Does it mean that I can call any address like a function?

```
// Is this legal?
int x = 69;
(&x)(3,78,69.456,'c','o','n','d','o','m');
```

What are the implications of THAT?

Comment: I wouldn't call a language "broken" and expect to get answers from people who know that language enough to be able to answer. Read the FAQ.

Comment: You can call any pointer as a function with a cast, but it's undefined behavior if it's not a valid function pointer.

Comment: What are you under the impression that a function is, if not an address in memory?

Comment: The C type system is borked. Pull some pointers out and you can get around any restriction. In that sense, C is broken. Allows for some crazy code though :P. @Larry: well, you can say that for anything if we're speaking C. In newer languages you've got things like first class functions right? it makes sense to think about them as something different to an address in memory

Comment: The C type system is perfect precisely _because_ it lets you tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing, don't restrict me." If you _really don't know what you're doing_, then you're screwed, but that's your fault.

Comment: @SethCarnegie that's what I love about C, you're practically in full control.

Comment: But then why even bother having types at all? Keep everything nice and type safe or don't bother and just treat everything as untyped. C can't make up it's mind. I don't deny it's a great language, but damn it get messy and confusing when you go about saying "I know what I'm doing leave me alone". Full control is great, and C is all about that... so drop the type system completely?

Comment: Types provide a bounty of useful features to a language, and you don't drop the type system completely when you do a raw cast or whatever (which, for the reasons you list, is normally frowned upon), but you override it in that specific instance. Also, the reason why you can override the type system completely when you want is because it's **types are completely compile-time concepts**. No type information is stored with data at runtime (which is part of why C  can be so fast). In short, if you don't like the power to or can't handle the complexity of writing portable assembly, C isn't for you.

Comment: This question should not have been closed.  In its current form, it is not at all vague or ambiguous: it is asking why the function call operator can be applied to a function pointer value without the need to dereference it.

Comment: @caf you're right, voted too quickly. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Calling C "broken"! This will not end well in SO!

Comment: @caf: In the form it had when closed it was argumentative and non-constructive.  The edited version (note is "removed silliness) is okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the contrary, pointers to functions are the *only* things callable as functions.  The definition of the function call operator starts out:

> The expression that denotes the called function shall have type
>   pointer to function returning `void` or returning an object type other
>   than an array type.

(This means that your second hypothetical is *not* legal, because `&x` is does not have a type that is a pointer to a function of any sort).

So, you might ask, why can you also call a function like this (where `myAwesomefunction` is an identifier declared as a function)?

```
myAwesomefunction(arg1,arg2,arg3...);
```

The answer is that a identifier like `myAwesomefunction` is a primary expression that evaluates to a function designator.  The definition of a function designator says:

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except
>   when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&`
>   operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’
>   is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function
>   returning type’’.

So formally, when you write `myAwesomefunction(arg1,arg2,arg3...);`, `myAwesomefunction` evaluates to a function designator, which then is converted to a pointer to the function, which is then used to call the function.

This conversion of a function designator to a pointer to the function is similar to the conversion of an expression with array type to a pointer to the array's first element.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the first is legal because &myAwesomefunction would be a pointer to a function with a known signature.  C++ lets you use the same syntax as calling a function in order to call a function pointer.

The second example is NOT legal because C++ knows that &x is pointer to an integer, NOT a function.

How is the first example possible?  Well the compiler knows the type of every expression.  I knows that "myAwesomefunction" is a function name.  It knows that "&myAwesomefunction" would be a pointer which points to myAwesomefunction and has the same signature as myAwesomefunction.  It then would examine the ()'s and know that given you have a function pointer, the only logical meaning is a function call.  It can ensure that whats inside the paranthesis matches the function's signature.

There's no ambiguity and there no reason for the compiler to force you to dereference a function pointer before you call it.  If you use parenthesis after a function pointer the compiler can figure out its a function call.